# JS error causing WordPress plugin to not work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to get a WordPress plugin "FlipBook" to display in a theme, however, in Console, the following URL will have the error listed below it: http://wiredhat.com/proofs/stc/wp/the-essential-guide/

> "Uncaught TypeError: s.find(...).addSwipeEvents is not a function" referencing flipbook.min.js?ver=4.5.1:1

When using a default WP theme, the error goes away and it shows the proper output:

http://demo.modded.com/stc/wp/the-guide/

I'm not quite sure what's causing the conflict. It would be helpful if someone would indicate how they came to the correct fix for this so I could answer these things myself in the future.

Comment: your theme is probably loading it is own version of jquery instead of letting WP take care of it.

Comment: In general, links to personal sites are discouraged here. We like questions to have a long life for the benefit of future readers, but we often find that questions of the form here-is-my-site suffer from link rot quite quickly. If you can use pasteboards such as JS Fiddle (as well as putting the code in the question itself) then this helps them live longer. Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the comment, however, this was referencing an error that I couldn't figure out the solution to and needed help with the existing problem. So rather than copy / paste every piece of code that could potentially be the problem, I posted a link to the functional reference. If that's against the community rules due to "link rot", I'm more than willing to visit elsewhere for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading two copies of jQuery in your page. First you load this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://wiredhat.com/proofs/stc/wp/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.3"></script>
```

and later you load:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`$.fn.addSwipeEvents` is defined after the first copy of jQuery is loaded, but it gets called after the second copy is loaded.

If you really need two versions of jQuery, you need to make use of `jQuery.noConflict()` to ensure that you call things with the save instance that they were loaded into. But if you don't, get rid of the second script tag.

Comment: LOL, awesome! Thank you so much for your help! :)